# Getting BAD request error in REST API when passing latitude and longitude value as a variable

Tags: api, request

I am new to this platform and also in coding.I am trying to get AQI using REST API from a server. It works fine when I am giving the latitude and longitude value directly to the API. But it is giving bad request 400 error when I am passing latitude and longitude value as a variable. Please help me.
My code snippet are as bellow

```
var aqival;
var level;
var sval;
var arrf;

var latitude =parseFloat(22.569719);
var longitude =parseFloat(88.36972);


var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current/airquality?lat=latitude&lon=longitude&key=API KEY", true);


console.log(latitude);
console.log(typeof(latitude));

request.onload = function () {

    var jsonobj = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

        aqival = jsonobj.data[0].aqi;
        level = "poor";

    } else {
            console.log('error');
            }
    var arr = "kolkata,wb";
    var arrpad = arr.padEnd(23,' ');        
    sval = String(aqival);
    var valpad = sval.padEnd(4,' ');
    var levelpad = level.padEnd(6,' ');
    arrf = arrpad + valpad + leve`enter code here`lpad;
    console.log(arrf);
    
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
}

request.send();
```

Comment: You are not passing any variables, you are passing the literal string `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: So how can I pass the latitude and longitude value through a variable in the url if I want to show AQI of different location? please help me.

Comment: You can use the [+ operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) to join multiple strings together.